# Firefox won't persist session in WhatsApp Web

Tags: macos, firefox, whatsapp

I scan the QR code, and WhatsApp Web works fine.

I close the tab, some time passes (I don't even restart Firefox), I open `web.whatsapp.com` again, and it shows the QR code all over again. I have to scan it with the phone every time. On Chrome I do it once on the device and that's that.

Anything I can do to fix this? I'm on macOS, Firefox 61.0b12 (64-bit).

Comment: In Options -> Privacy & Security -> Cookies and Site Data -> Exceptions, verify that the website isn't excluded from storing cookies. I've had weird issues with sites getting added to that list without me knowing.

Comment: Yeah, not listing as an exception atm, and inspecting the data does show cookies for `web.whatsapp.com`. I also made sure to turn off all uMatrix filters for it. Weird stuff.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but did you check the "keep me signed in" checkbox under the QR code? If so, try deleting the cookies and "logging out" that browser session on the WhatsApp phone app.

Comment: Yeah, I did check it. I found a potential lead: inspecting the cookies in the Storage tab of the Developer Tools, I saw that the two cookies that WhatsApp Web stores have the `Expires` attribute set to `Session`, which seems to lead to [unpredictable expiration behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36421888/105132). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034817/105132), I set them to expire on `Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT`. Let's see if that solves it.

Comment: No luck. Cookies got reverted to `Expires on` === `Session`, got logged out again :/

Comment: What worked for me was to disable my installed firefox add-ons (Also I cleared all history, data and physically went and deleted the cookie files)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of this issue by allowing cookies for the WhatsApp website as an exception.

**Preferences >> Privacy & Security >> Cookies and Site Data**
[image]

Due to the "delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed" is ticked it will remove all the cookies related to the sign-in process. By adding the website URL as an exception, the related cookies will remain even after closing the browser. You can add those exceptions by clicking the button "Manage Exceptions..".

[image]

Type the URL and click the allow button. It will add two records( don't know why two). After that, you can close and open the browser again. Then if you have already sign-in to WhatsApp, it will redirect to where you want.